# Как правильно скруглить табы в QTabBar? QTabBar::RoundedNorth и QTabBar::RoundedSouth

Tags: qt5, qt-designer

Всем привет!
При использовании `border` и `border-radius` получаю такой обрыв на краях верхней границы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу получить прямую обрезанную скруглениями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прочитал про `QTabBar::RoundedNorth` и `QTabBar::RoundedSouth` а вот примера не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ссылку:
https://www.pythontutorial.net/pyqt/pyqt-qtabwidget/

по примеру использовал так:

```
tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
tab.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
tab.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.TabPosition.West)
```

Получается тип `Triangular` или `Rounded`
и расположение табов `North South West East`,
а значит эти параметры отпадают.